# Why do Scala function types conform to the FunctionN traits?

Tags: scala

In other words, what purpose do the FunctionN traits serve? Do they exist to enable the compiler to know how to treat functions as first class values? I.e. when a function accepts another function as an argument, FunctionN is needed by the compiler to do type-checking?

I want to make sure I understand the answer [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177043/the-idea-of-functionn-in-scala-functionaljava) correctly and unfortunately don't have enough reputation points to comment on the existing answer.

Comment: `FunctionN` means function with n parameters. See detail here -     [`function types`] (http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#function-types )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what purpose do the FunctionN traits serve?

They serve the same purpose most traits do, to create structure and provide a common abstraction over concrete implementation. `FunctionN` is used by the underlying compiler when you use [anonymous function syntax](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/anonymous-function-syntax.html), and provides the implementation via it's `apply` method.

> Do they exist to enable the compiler to know how to treat functions as first class values

Again, they exist to create a calling convention for functions in Scala, since methods don't have a value as far as the type system goes. They are the underlying implementation for the type system to express anonymous functions, which are first class values in the type system.

> when a function accepts another function as an argument, FunctionN is needed by the compiler to do type-checking?

`FunctionN` is a type like any other, where type checking is being done like any other type. One thing to note us that the compiler is actually *aware* of the trait and underlying implementations since it has to utilize it for function values.

Comment: "They are the underlying implementation for the type system to express anonymous functions, which are first class values in the type system." --> This expresses what I was trying to verify, in a clearer way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do Scala **function types** conform to the `FunctionN` traits?

To simplify the type system: what would be the alternative? Adding function types to the type system. But why add function types to the type system if you can get by with just a simple polymorphic nominal trait, which Scala already has anyway.

You need some type for functions. You can either add function types or you can use what's already there: generic traits. One of Scala's main goals is simplicity.